# Unreachable areas in the new navigation using the keyboard

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, keyboard-shortcuts, new-nav, accessibility

Using only your keyboard to navigate around Stack Overflow (and here on MSE), it is not possible to change the "filter" dropdown using your keyboard. It jumps directly from the bounty indicator to the "show" dropdown, and never actually makes it back to "filter".

[image: The "show" dropdown is focused instead of "filter"]

This only happens in the "Need answer" tab and the bounty tab, only with the "filter" dropdown. I did not have any issues getting to the other dropdowns at all, and was successful in changing options using only the keyboard. Additionally, if you do manage to open the "filter" dropdown, the last option ("custom tags") is also not reachable by the keyboard.

This still happens with the filter dropdown, even with the updated design.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Speaking of the "custom tags" option, you cannot close the tags area by hitting the "cancel" button, because that too is not reachable using the keyboard.

[image: The "cancel" button is not reachable at all.]

These appear to be caused by the `href` attribute not being included in the `<a>` tags, without any `tabindex` being specified. Specifying a `href` attribute (even just `#`) brings them back into the tab order.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Also, if you select "order by" in the keyboard shortcut menu (activated by "?"), the "bounty" tab (activated by pressing "d") does not have any helper text next to it.

[image: There is no text next to the "d" key in the help menu]

I suspect this is because the "bounty" tab does not actually have any text next to it, unlike the other three tabs.

Comment: @Skilvvz Any reason why an accessibility issue would be labelled as a feature request instead of a bug? Unless you interpreted it as "I'd like to be able to interact with Stack Overflow using a keyboard and have an idea of what is going on".

Comment: Because it was not planned for this (alpha) release in the first place, so it's not a bug or a regression, but simply a valuable feature we will implement at some point.